# Getting a warning of "unexpected argument" for PyQGIS processing parameter in PyCharm

Tags: qgis, python, qgis-processing, pyqgis-3, pycharm

When specifying named argument for any type of `QgsProcessingParameter`, PyCharm complains of an `Unexpected Argument` warning. Although it doesn't cause any issue to the execution of the Processing algorithm in QGIS, it's kind of annoying when coding. I know I can turn off the inspection on this in PyCharm, but I hope there's some trick that I can use to make PyCharm understand the names (just as below: `name`, `description` and `types`). The complete definition of the class can be found [here](https://qgis.org/pyqgis/master/core/QgsProcessingParameterFeatureSource.html).

```
def initAlgorithm(self, config=None):

    self.addParameter(
        QgsProcessingParameterFeatureSource(
            name=self.INPUT,
            description=self.tr('Input layer'),
            types=[QgsProcessing.TypeVectorAnyGeometry]
        )
    )
```

Comment: I think it is a bug.